# Python3.3+Django+mysqldb+pycharm

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pycharm

I have installed https://github.com/clelland/MySQL-for-Python-3 Mysqldb for python3. But there is an exeption in pycharmw hen I try to use:

```
from django.db import connections
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I'm working on mac and have the latest django. My config for db is `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'` What could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Python 3 driver for MySQL. Please consider using PostgreSQL or SQLite.